# Uploading an image to Wolfram with "png" or "jpg" suffix

Tags: image, wolfram-cloud

Using `CloudExport` one can get images of Wolfram objects into the cloud:

> [image]

**Problem:** Those urls don't come with a `*.png` or `*.jpeg` suffix (like, i.e., imgur images do). This causes parsing/rendering errors in various programs that I use. So is there a way to tell Wolfram to give me a link with a `png` suffix? If not Wolfram, is there another service I can use (through Wolfram APIs)?

Comment: Why not add the suffix to the name, e.g., `CloudExport[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], "PNG", "plot.png"]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll That worked.